# Handling GAS Listbox multiple selection

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm struggling to handle a multiple selection listbox in a handler function. My listbox entries contain commas, ideally i want to get an array of the selected items in the handler but it seems to be a single string.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

thanks

```
function doGet() {
...
var completedReportsList = app.createListBox(true)
.setId('list')
.addItem("Bloggs, Joe")
.addItem("Doe, Jane");
var generatePDFButton = app.createButton("Generate PDFs")
.setId("generatePDFButton");
var generatePDFButtonHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('generatePDF')
.addCallbackElement(completedReportsList)
generatePDFButton.addClickHandler(generatePDFButtonHandler);
...
}

function generatePDF(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
Logger.log(e.parameter.list.length); // undefined
Logger.log(e.parameter.list); // <- how to parse multiple selected items?
return app;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListBox accepts 2 parameters, a "shown" value and a "returned" value. The second parameter is optional and if not present the returned value becomes the shown value.

Could it be possible for you to use this second field with a value that does not contain commas, for example using a | separator so that you could easily rebuild your original value with a replace in each array element?

Code would be as follows :

*(you also forgot to give a name to your list, that's why you got length=undefined for e.parameter.list)*

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test');

  var completedReportsList = app.createListBox(true)
  .setId('list').setName('list')
  .addItem("Bloggs, Joe","Bloggs| Joe")
  .addItem("Doe, Jane","Doe| Jane");// this could of course be obtained in the script with a .replace string method.
  var generatePDFButton = app.createButton("Generate PDFs").setId("generatePDFButton");
  var generatePDFButtonHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('generatePDF').addCallbackElement(completedReportsList);
  generatePDFButton.addClickHandler(generatePDFButtonHandler);
  app.add(completedReportsList).add(generatePDFButton)
  return app
}

function generatePDF(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log(e.parameter.list.split(',').length); // undefined
  var listValues = e.parameter.list.split(','); // an array of values
  for(var n in listValues){
    Logger.log(listValues[n].replace('|',','));
  }
  return app;  
}
```

And here is a modified version that creates the alternate fields automatically in the doGet function :

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test');
  var completedReportsList = app.createListBox(true).setId('list').setName('list');
  var items = ["Bloggs, Joe","Doe, Jane"];
  for(var n in items){
    item = items[n];
    modItem = items[n].replace(',','|');
    completedReportsList.addItem(item,modItem);
  }
  var generatePDFButton = app.createButton("Generate PDFs").setId("generatePDFButton");
  var generatePDFButtonHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('generatePDF').addCallbackElement(completedReportsList);
  generatePDFButton.addClickHandler(generatePDFButtonHandler);
  app.add(completedReportsList).add(generatePDFButton)
  return app
}
```

Comment: thanks, using the value parameter of the listitem i was able to solve it